# Drive to 0 and cleanup day

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

So I'm setting this as a [chat event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule) a few weeks ahead. At the end of October, we'll do a massive drive to:

- push all unanswered questions to have a **useful and informative** answer
- add as many tag descriptions as possible
- hunt out spam accounts and 'take care' of them
- chat in the chat room while we do all this!
- hunt down and 'clothe' naked URLS

Please - sign up now at the link above.  You've got plenty of time, and all day that day to do something.

Comment: Eh, we should also have a drive to get out those pesky nekkid URLs..

Comment: I would choose stronger wording than "to have an answer" - I have noticed in previous such drives that some fluff answers have come in just to bolster the numbers and I think this is a bad thing. Can't we add in "good" or "useful" or "relevant" or some other positive and constructive adjective?

Comment: @hippietrail - updated :)